# In Couchbase is it possible to set and get XATTR value for non JSON documents?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I put binary data in Couchbase. But for my new use case, I need to set a field called created_date along with my document. I was thinking of using xattr for this.

The purpose of this field "created_date" will be to use it for comparison between two versions of the same document (let's say doc_1)

For e.g.

doc_1 - created_date1 - In couchbase currently

doc_1 - created_date2 - Received from upstream

And I need to compare created_date2 vs created_date1 and replace the upstream document in Couchbase only if created_date2 > created_date1 .

I am using Java SDK for Couchbase. I was using upsert for inserting/updating in Couchbase which supports transcoder for non-JSON documents in UpsertOptions.

```
UpsertOptions upsertOptions = UpsertOptions.upsertOptions()
                .transcoder(transcoder)
```

But for setting Xattr I think I must use

```
collection.mutateIn
```

as MutateInSpec supports xattr

```
MutateInSpec.replace("created_date", created_date).xattr())
```

But I am not able to find an option to specify transcoder in

```
MutateInOptions.mutateInOptions()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know of a way to upsert/insert a binary document and set its xattrs at the same time. It might be necessary to upsert first and then set the xattrs with a separate call to `mutateIn`. You'll probably want to use CAS from the upsert result when making the `mutateIn` request  to make sure nobody else is trying to do the same thing at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. But this means making an un-necessary network call. 
Not sure why this is not supported though

Answer (score 0):

So you need to write the binary document body at the same time as writing an xattr?  This is possible, you can do:

```
    collection.mutateIn("doc-id", Arrays.asList(

            // Make sure xattrs go first in the specs list
            MutateInSpec.upsert("xattr-path", "xattr-field").xattr(),

            // You can replace the document's body with binary data like this
            MutateInSpec.replace("", new byte[]{1,2,3,4})));
```